# Change structure of dictionary in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, nested

Is there a way of changing structure of nested dictionary?
I have a column in dataframe with many rows of dictionaries, which looks like that:

```
[{'a': 'b', 'c': {'c1': 'v1', 'c2': 'v2'}}, {'a': 'b1', 'c': {'c1': 'x1', 'c2': 'x2'}}, {'a': 'b2', 'c': {'c1': 'n1', 'c2': 'n2'}}]
```

Is there a way of modifying structure, so that it will looks like

```
[{'b': {'c1': 'v1', 'c2': 'v2'}}, {'b1': {'c1': 'x1', 'c2': 'x2'}}, {'b2': {'c1': 'n1', 'c2': 'n2'}}]
```

without changing actual values?

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with pandas

Comment: How else do you work with dataframes? Used to work with them using pandas, don't know how else to change json files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read about the function [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) in pandas.

You build a function that essentially does your dictionary manipulation :

```
def transformation(row):
    # Where 'correspondingColumn' is the name of your initial column
    return {row[correspondingColumn]['a']: row[correspondingColumn]['c']}
```

Then you can use `apply()` to call this over all the rows of your DataFrame :

```
# Where 'newCol' is the name of your new column, or if you want to replace the other one, it can be the same
my_df['newCol'] = my_df.apply(transformation, axis = 1)
```

Complete example :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col':[{'a': 'b', 'c': {'c1': 'v1', 'c2': 'v2'}}]
})

def transformation(row):
    return {row['col']['a']: row['col']['c']}

df['newCol'] = df.apply(transformation, axis = 1)

# Output
                                         col                           newCol
0  {'a': 'b', 'c': {'c1': 'v1', 'c2': 'v2'}}  {'b': {'c1': 'v1', 'c2': 'v2'}}
```

**Update for list of dictionaries :**

```
def transformation(row):
    return [{elem['a']: elem['c']} for elem in row['col']]
```

Comment: Thank you. That seems to work. Is there a way to make it for list of dictionaries? Like [{'a': 'b', 'c': {'c1': 'v1', 'c2': 'v2'}}, {'a': 'b1', 'c': {'c1': 'v1', 'c2': 'v2'}}, {'a': 'b2', 'c': {'c1': 'v1', 'c2': 'v2'}}].

Comment: Of course, you can use list comprehension in order to do this operation on multiple elements. I'm guessing the result is a list of dictionaries as well, see the updated answer.

Comment: Something seems to not working. When I try apply with axis = 1, it raises TypeError: transformation() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'. Without axis argument it worked with simple dict (return {row['col']['a']: row['col']['c']}), but with updated it raises error TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: It's working for me, did you call it properly with this exact line `df['newCol'] = df.apply(transformation, axis = 1)` ? Your Traceback is confusing me because it seems you are trying to use `transformation(axis = 1)` and axis is not a parameter for this function. Instead, both `axis = 1` and `transformation` are `apply()` arguments (notice the lack of parenthesis after transformation).

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Tried to do that with table with this single column, and it didn't work (not sure why). But with the whole table it works perfect. Thank you

Comment: Most probably because there is no fail safe, it the current element of the row provided is not a valid list, an error will be thrown, you can use if/else or try/exept statements in the transformation function to make sure this doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
d = {'a': 'b', 'c': {'c1': 'v1', 'c2': 'v2'}}
dic={}
dic['b'] = d['c']
dic
```

Output:

```
{'b': {'c1': 'v1', 'c2': 'v2'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
dict([d.values()])
```